# How to use setItemIconTintList with specific item? [BottomNavigationView]

Tags: android, material-design, android-drawable, android-bottomnavigationview

I'm trying to show the user photo in `BottomNavigationView` but I don't know how to do it correctly.

**This solution is working fine but other items will lose their colors**

```
Drawable drawable = activityMainBinding.activityMainBottomNavigationViewBottomNavigation.getMenu().findItem(R.id.menu_bottom_navigation_user).getIcon();
activityMainBinding.activityMainBottomNavigationViewBottomNavigation.setItemIconTintList(null);
```

[The Code Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A1sO3.jpg)

**I tried to solve the problem by applying the setItemIconTintList method on the user-item only**

```
Drawable drawable = activityMainBinding.activityMainBottomNavigationViewBottomNavigation.getMenu().findItem(R.id.menu_bottom_navigation_user).getIcon();
drawable.setState(null);
drawable.setTintList(null);
drawable.clearColorFilter();
activityMainBinding.activityMainBottomNavigationViewBottomNavigation.getMenu().findItem(R.id.menu_bottom_navigation_user).setIcon(drawable);
```

[The Code Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tMqxz.jpg)

How can I solve the problem?

I hope someone shows the attached images directly because I cannot do it.

Answer (score 1):

You Can Use This Code:

```
Menu navMenu = activityMainBinding.activityMainBottomNavigationViewBottomNavigation.getMenu();
MenuItem menuItem = navMenu.findItem(R.id.menu_bottom_navigation_user);
Glide.with(context)
    .asBitmap()
    .load("your image")
    .apply(RequestOptions
            .circleCropTransform()
            .placeholder("Your PlaceHolder"))
    .into(new SimpleTarget<Bitmap>() {
        public void onResourceReady(Bitmap resource, Transition<Bitmap> transition) {
            menuItem.setIcon(new BitmapDrawable(context.getResource(), resource));
        }
    })
```

Comment: Sorry but your solution is not working and the `SimpleTarget` is deprecated.